# Sending multiple content email to one recipient in PHP

Tags: php, email, foreach

I had a problem where I want to send multiple content to only one recipient

here is my code

```
$stringx = explode(",",$_POST["row"]);

  foreach($stringx as $mvalue)
  {
    $ids = explode("_",$mvalue);
    $rowid = intval($ids[0]); // 0
    $lakeid = intval($ids[1]); //5312
    $sql = getDataArray("SELECT Type FROM DB WHERE LakeID=$lakeid ",$link);
             $msg = $sql[2][0]["Type"];


          $contents = " Type  : $msg <br/> 
         ";
  }

  sendemail("hamirul@mydomain.com", "Hamirul", "mydomain", "automailer@mydomain","Lake Link ",$contents,$link);
```

The problem is when I try to send email, it only send one '$content' . I want to send multiple content at once. If I code like this, it will send 2 content but it will email me two(2) times.

```
  foreach($stringx as $mvalue)
  {

    $contents = "// something ";

     sendemail($contents,$link);
  }
```

I want to get 2 contents in one email.

Comment: to much missing code here to be able to anser this

Comment: the code work well , i just want to know how to get multiple content in one email

Comment: well post the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this inside loop

$contents .= "some value";

So, code should look like:

$contents = "";

foreach($stringx as $mvalue)
{

```
  .....

  $contents .= " Type  : $msg <br/> 
 ";

  // Or,

  $contents = $contents . " Type : $msg. <br/> ";


  .....
```

}

sendemail($contents,$link);

Comment: i tried it , but still the same . I only got one $content

Comment: foreach($stringx as $mvalue)
   $contents = "";
{

$contents = "// something ";

 sendemail($contents,$link);
}
here

Comment: still the same . it only send one $content

Comment: Please give more than this code.. Problem may be somewhere else

Comment: My code should have worked... Just concatenate all the contents.. Add a . before = sign to make $contents .=